# Find the matrix A that transforms a non invertible 3x3 matrix to 2x2 matrix

Tags: matrices

I'm trying to figure out an elegant way (or any way that doesn't involve multiplying everything out) to do this matrix algebra but am stuck. The equation is $A \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 2\\ 2 & 4 & 4 \\ 2 & 4 & 9 \end{bmatrix}A^T = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 4 \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: One way is to use $LDL^T$ decomposition (i.e., diagonalize the symmetric bilinear forms with nonorthogonal(!) matrices) to construct $A$ but it still involves a fair amount of multiplying.

Comment: Hint: left-multiplying by the $i$th row of the identity matrix picks out the $i$th row; right-multiplying by the $j$th column of the identity picks out the $j$th column.